# Provide an example of weighted directed graph with defective Laplacian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Define the Laplacian matrix as $L = D - A$. Here, $A$ is the adjacency matrix of a directed weighted graph with $n$ vertices so that the entries $A_{ij}$ of $A$ are equal to a positive weight if there is an arrow form the vertex $j$ to $i$ and $0$ otherwise, and $D = \operatorname{diag}(\sum_{i=1}^n A_{i1},\cdots,\sum_{i=1}^n A_{in})$.

Can one come up with an example of weighted directed graph for which $L$ would be defective matrix?

Here, by "defective matrix" I mean a square matrix that does not have a complete basis of eigenvectors, and is therefore not diagonalizable.

Comment: By defective, do you mean the matrix is not invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph $1 \to 2 \to \dots \to n$ has Laplacian matrix
$$
L = \pmatrix{
1&\\
-1&1&\\
&-1&\ddots\\
&& \ddots&1\\
&&&-1&0
}
$$
where the unwritten entries are zeros. This matrix is defective for $n \geq 3$.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake in my question. $D$ contains sums over columns. Additionally, the off-diagonal elements of the matrix must be non-positive.

Comment: @lyskiman see my latest edit

Comment: thank you, this answers the question and kills an idea. I need a better one now.